# How to make a popup div hover over a link in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

How to make a popup hover over a link in jquery?

```
<div id="floatbar">
    <a href="" onclick="make it float 10px under this yay">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you at least provide a drawing/screenshot of what it should look like? This is not enough information to work with.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you referring to a tooltip?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the jquery

```
$("#floatbar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(".popup").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

the css

```
#floatbar {
    position:relative;
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    height:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    display:none;
}
```

the html

```
<a id="floatbar" href="#">
    <div class="popup">Hi there</div>
    click here
</a>
```

Comment: Hey Anderson, Its working its just there is nothing to click as there was no text in the link. See my edits above. or just visit your jsfiddle demo and put the words 'click here' in the a tags just under the popup div.

Answer (score 11):

Pure css solution:

```
<div id="floatbar">
    <a href="" onclick="make it float 10px under this yay">Link</a>
    <div class="box">Popup box</div>
</div>

.box {
     display:none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 30px; 
     left: 10px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

a:hover + .box {
     display:block;   
}
```

All you have to do is add a `<div class="box">(popup text)</div>` below the link and it'll work for every link that has such a box.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcdqt/

Comment: On mouseLeave the **.box**  div is hidden. So I can not keep mouse on the shown .box div. How can I also hover the .box div when it's shown?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its easier when you use something like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) for jQuery or another Lightbox alternative?